# Error executing sencha commands

Tags: extjs

please any body help in below issue

I have sencha version `4.0.1.45`

when I run `sencha app build`, It gives below error.

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.HttpRepository.fixUrl(HttpRepository.java:151)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.HttpRepository.<init>(HttpRepository.java:36)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository$Type$1.create(RemoteRepository.jav
a:33)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:74)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:102)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:106)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl$1.accept(RepositoryRemo
teManagerImpl.java:28)
     at java.io.File.listFiles(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl.<init>(RepositoryRemote
ManagerImpl.java:26)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.<init>(LocalRepository.java:100)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getLocalRepository(Wo
rkspaceRepository.java:262)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getCatalog(WorkspaceR
epository.java:241)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.resolvePackageModels(
WorkspaceRepository.java:117)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.resolvePackageEnviron
ments(WorkspaceRepository.java:97)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getRequiredPackag
eEnvironments(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:187)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPack
ageEnvironment.java:398)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePl
uginCommands.java:23)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java
:130)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:148)

[ERR]
The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (3.1.1.274)
the current is 4.0.1.45.
Please run "sencha app upgrade" to update to 4.0.1.45.
```

when i try to upgrade sencha with

`sencha app upgrade` it again gives error.

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.HttpRepository.fixUrl(HttpRepository.java:151)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.HttpRepository.<init>(HttpRepository.java:36)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository$Type$1.create(RemoteRepository.ja
a:33)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:74)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:102)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RemoteRepository.<init>(RemoteRepository.java:106)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl$1.accept(RepositoryRem
teManagerImpl.java:28)
     at java.io.File.listFiles(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.RepositoryRemoteManagerImpl.<init>(RepositoryRemot
ManagerImpl.java:26)
     at com.sencha.tools.pkg.LocalRepository.<init>(LocalRepository.java:100)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getLocalRepository(W
rkspaceRepository.java:262)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.getCatalog(Workspace
epository.java:241)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.resolvePackageModels
WorkspaceRepository.java:117)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.WorkspaceRepository.resolvePackageEnviro
ments(WorkspaceRepository.java:97)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.getRequiredPacka
eEnvironments(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:187)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPac
ageEnvironment.java:398)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironmen
.java:224)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$UpgradeCommand.execute(AppCommands.j
va:284)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:148)

[ERR]
The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (3.1.1.274)
the current is 4.0.1.45.
Please run "sencha app upgrade" to update to 4.0.1.45.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should download the latest sdk.
then `sencha app upgrade /path/to/new_version_of_sdk`

hope it helps-